# Have the repositories been shortened?

Tags: apt, repository

I just sudo apt-get updated my repos and it took in total, 5 seconds to get everything. It usually takes 2/3 minutes. Have the repos been shortened?

Comment: 2/3 mins sounds way too much. For me it usually tikes about 5-10 seconds

Comment: 2/3 minutes for update? I doubt it...Do you mean upgrade?

Comment: @^^ It depends on connection speed.

Comment: I have 100kb/s connection when I'm downloading.

Comment: Can you post the output of the command?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/d076iex0

Answer (score 0):

If you have last updated lists, `apt` will download nothing. So all lines start with `Hit:` (or `Ign:`) but few or none are `Get:`. You should get short time.

Example, mine with 2Mbps or ~256KBps  connection.

- 7 sec when every thing was updated
- ~10 min after 1 week from last update (more time because I've source code repository active)